# Explain why $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(x))\text{dx}=-\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cot(x)$dx

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**Background(optional info)**: This comes from an example [(3.3)](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf) of Feynman's trick or differentiating under the integral sign by parameter substitution. The integral 
$-\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cot(x)$dx is evaluated ($=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)$) by adding a parameter b, modifying the integrand, and switching the integral and differential $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{db}}I(b)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\partial}{\partial{b}}\frac{\tan^{-1}(b\tan(x))}{\tan(x)}dx$$ then taking the $\lim_{b\to 1}$ after integrating w.r.t b.

---

Anyway, **my question is** at the end it is stated that this is another way to integrate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(x))\text{dx}$ because
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(x))\text{dx}=-\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cot(x)dx \tag{1}$$

How do you convert the first into the second integral in (1)?

Comment: Integration by parts.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I mean, how do you convert the integrand of the first into the second, not how to solve it.

Comment: Integration by parts.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Aha! I see it now.